# Removing gvfsd-smb-browse

Tags: package-management, samba

I just had the problem where `gvfsd-smb-browse` starts taking up the whole cpu and needs to be killed.  Searching the Internet I see this is not uncommon, and there doesn't seem to be a general solution.  As I do not use samba I would like to just remove `gvfsd-smb-browse`; but it is installed with the larger package `gvfsd-backends` that I probably do not want to remove.  Is there a way to get rid of it?

Comment: Related question with unfortunately only backend-specific answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1285637/gvfs-how-to-disable-a-certain-backend

Answer (score 6):

I was having the same issue after upgrading to 16.04. What I did was change the permissions on gvfsd-smb-browse so that it can only be executed as sudo or by root. Now gvfsd-smb-browse doesn't run on startup. Below is how you can change the permissions.

```
sudo chmod 744 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-smb-browse
```

Not sure if it is a real solution to the underlying problem. But it does resolve the cpu usage issue by not running gvfsd-smb-browse on startup.

Comment: That's an interesting solution.  I considered simply deleting it as well.  Does it serve a useful purpose that you wanted to keep it around for?  Also, what happens when `gvfsd-backends` is upgraded -- do the permissions get reset?

Comment: Well it is a virtual file system, and is pretty much used everywhere for mounting devices etc. So it won't be a good idea to remove it. This particular file "gvfsd-smb-browse" is used to browse windows file system, so if you are not mounting windows volumes on startup then there is no need to run it.

Comment: What happens when gvfsd-backends is upgraded -- do the permissions get reset?

Answer (score 1):

Well, The upstream package didn't set up a configuration file or folder. I think these folders are more suitable to be somewhere in `/etc`

```
/usr/share/gvfs/mounts/
/usr/share/gvfs/remote-volume-monitors/
```

Or have at least an override there. Anyway let's make one.

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/gvfs/enabled
sudo cp -ar /usr/share/gvfs/mounts /etc/gvfs/enabled
sudo cp -ar /usr/share/gvfs/remote-volume-monitors /etc/gvfs/enabled

echo 'export GVFS_MONITOR_DIR="/etc/gvfs/enabled/remote-volume-monitors/"' | sudo tee /etc/profile.d/gvfs.sh
echo 'export GVFS_MOUNTABLE_DIR="/etc/gvfs/enabled/mounts/"' | sudo tee -a /etc/profile.d/gvfs.sh
sudo chmod +x /etc/profile.d/gvfs.sh
```

Now, you have full control:

- Disable: remove/rename back-ends & monitors definition files from `/etc/gvfs/enabled/mounts/` & `/etc/gvfs/enabled/remote-volume-monitors/` respectively.
- Enable: copy back from origin or rename back (`.mount` &  `.monitor` extension)

I have tested these instructions in Ubuntu 20.10, only with monitors for quick test (`ps ax | grep -i gvfs`).

Reference:

- https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/gvfs/doc

Answer (score 0):

There is a [similar question](/q/762977) where the workaround is to edit your `smb.conf` like in [Launchpad bug #1409032](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gvfs/+bug/1409032/comments/29).
It worked for me reducing CPU usage and really sped things up!

I just put this line under the `globals` statement after backing up my `/etc/samba/smb.conf` file:

```
[global]
name resolve order = wins lmhosts bcast
```

*Note:* wins is no longer necessary on the majority of systems, especially those after the year 2000.