# Ubuntu 16.04 or 14.04?

Tags: downgrade

So my college teacher told me today that, for developing, the Ubuntu 14.04 is more stable than the 16.04 and also said that there is a huge diference and with the actual version I'm probably going to have an adventure trying to fix thousands of errors. So I got worried because I installed the 16.04 and can't find a link that gives me something like UEFI Bootable Ubuntu 14.04. Was wondering if you guys can help me showing how I can uninstall the 16 and where to get the 14 and if you think it is really necessary the older version.

Ps.: He is the Object Oriented teacher and we will be using c++, java and ruby.
     It is a dual boot with Windows 10 and I do not have intention of loosing Windows files :D

Comment: No need to worry, version 16 is lts one, and c++, java, ruby all will work fine

Comment: If you're worried and if it's only for development why don't you just install 14.04 in a virtual machine and use it only if you have problems with 16.04 (which you probably won't)?

Comment: @waltinator I have not read any of them and all of my Ubuntu/Windows dual boot installations (which have been quite a few now) were successful. Actually I don't see why e.g. POST should be related at all.

Comment: @rancho - just as an example of touble with 16.04 - i've already had trouble because of a third party java based application not supporting the MySQL pacakaged in 16.04. 14.04 is also an LTS and will be around another 3 years.

Comment: Instead of a dual boot I'd recommend using a virtual machine instead. I've been running several Linux desktops on Windows 7/10 host with [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) for 5+ years.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I am using 16.04 and I have very few problems. On some wi-fi networks when I mount my windows partitions [gvfs goes at 100%](https://askubuntu.com/a/805322/498541). Killing the process fixes it with no problems. There are reports of a lot of people having problems with the network manager and wi-fi networks but I haven't seen that. Overall I 'd say 16.04.1 is quite stable.

If I were you before downgrading I would install all the software I need for the course and test them to see they are working fine. If they do then I 'd suggest you stay at 16.04 because of the newer features it has, notable among them better secure boot support.

If you run into any problems and decide to install 14.04 you can get it from [here](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/).

Comment: Can confirm wifi issues. 16.04 seems to have issues with older routers.

Answer (score 4):

There are reasons why Ubuntu update their system. If you don't have any strong will for Ubuntu 14.04, Ubuntu 16.04 will be fine. Also, there are some dependencies that won't work on 14.04.

Maybe problems won't happen when you learn Java, C++, etc. From a further perspective you should install 16.04.

If you are afraid of losing your Windows files. Just use AOMEI Partitioner.(not an ad :D) You can free some space like 20GB from your Windows without losing data. Then use the free space to install Ubuntu and don't let it partition again.

Answer (score 2):

You can always create a [Docker container](https://docs.docker.com/engine/understanding-docker/) using a Ubuntu 16.04 image (as it is in the  [oficial Ubuntu github repository](https://hub.docker.com/_/ubuntu/)) and test your projects there. It will be way more lightweight than a virtual machine, and it will give you an ide aof what problems you may find.

Answer (score 1):

I am using ubuntu 16.04, and it is working absolutely fine. c++, java, and ruby all works fine in it. Ubuntu is updating its versions because it tries to fix some errors which had issues with the previous versions. So i suggest you to install all the programs you need and try to run them in 16.04 first. If they are working fine then keep using ubuntu 16.04. If you need 14.04 then you can get it from http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/.