# gvfs how to disable a certain backend?

Tags: configuration, gvfs

I need to disable a certain gvfs backend as I suspect it to cause problems with an external device (in detail I am talking about the afc backend).

Unfortunately I wasn't able to find anything on where and how to configure gvfs.

What do I have to do to disable the afc backend of gvfs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The different backends of gvfs are installed as user services, you can manage them using `systemctl --user`.

You can stop the **afc backend** using this command (Ubuntu 20.04):

```
systemctl --user stop gvfs-afc-volume-monitor.service
```

or disable it permanently

```
systemctl --user disable gvfs-afc-volume-monitor.service
```

Note that this only disables the service for the current user. If multiple users are logged in (e.g. via ssh) for the second user the service will still start.