# How do I prevent nautius from showing sftp devices?

Tags: nautilus, sftp, gvfs, amazon, nautilus-extensions

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 x64.

When I browse 'other locations' in Nautilus it's showing me a bunch of strange devices.  With names starting with "dp-" and then digits.  I used 'avahi-browse -avr' and that revealed them to be SFTP services running on amazon echo devices.

```
=   eth0 IPv4 dp-6x4x0xWX                                   SSH Remote Terminal  local
   hostname = [dp-6x4x0xWX.local]
   address = [192.168.xx.39]
   port = [22]
   txt = []
=   eth0 IPv4 dp-6x4x0xWX [00:00:00:00:00:00]               Workstation          local
   hostname = [dp-6x4x0xWX.local]
   address = [192.168.xx.39]
   port = [9]
   txt = []
=   eth0 IPv4 dp-6x4x0xWX                                   SFTP File Transfer   local
   hostname = [dp-6x4x0xWX.local]
   address = [192.168.xx.39]
   port = [22]
```

Uh, yeah, ok.  I don't need to browse into these.  I don't have anything on the wire that's providing sftp that I need to see via Nautilus.

Is is possible to configure Nautilus to ignore and not show these?

Comment: from your statement, i am assuming you want Nautilus to ignore them vice preventing them from being advertised?

Comment: I have no circumstances where I need to use sftp resources from a UI session on this machine.  it appears Nautilus is building the list it shows from mDNS records.  I can't prevent the devices from publishing themselves, but I'd certainly like to have a way to prevent them from being shown in nautilus.

Comment: if i chmod 000 the gvfsd-sftp library it throws an access denied error when selecting one of these.  but that didn't prevent them from being shown.  

if I leave gvfsd-sftp accessible, then there's a several second delay if one of the devices is selected, until it times out.  

so is there a place in a config file somewhere that I can tell Nautilus what it should ignore?

Comment: i think.. and i say "think" you can prevent them from being published, you just cant prevent them from being discovered... I "think" there is a difference...  i doubt it would work because of that, but you could look in /etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf and set publishing to "no"... there is somewhere else where those entries/services are kept together individually in a directory... i just really cant remember and i don't have that configured so I cant look... it would be an empty directory for me. I have not found anywhere to turn/off or filter the discovery from the nautilus side

Comment: I'm not talking about hiding anything that THIS machine is publishing.  I'm talking about telling THIS machine to IGNORE what other machines might have published.  I can't stop them from publishing.  

And I'd be willing to nuke SFTP support in Nautilus to do it.

I've raised this question over on the gnome discourse.  

https://discourse.gnome.org/t/having-nautilus-hide-sftp-resources/4621

Comment: is there anything in your ~/.config/nautilus/servers ?

Comment: no, the file doesn't exist

Comment: do they show up in `gio mount -li` ??? If so you may be able to unmount them with the gio command

Comment: have you tried this one? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1285637/gvfs-how-to-disable-a-certain-backend